# Android Toolbar свой стиль

Tags: android, toolbar

Есть задача в наименование активити, между букв (вместо одной буквы) запихнуть логотип компании.

Есть ли возможность как-то кастомизировать `Toolbar`, чтобы это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью **xml**-разметки, вставив **ImageView** с логотипом:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/whitecolor"
        android:text=""
        android:transitionName="actionBar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:src="@drawable/companylogo"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```